# git-rebase: Converge two diverging branches/repositories

Tags: git

Assume I have the following situation:

There is a repository main of User Foo. User Bar forks this repository, so both repositories are in sync. Now user Bar implements a feature and creates a local branch called "barbranch". By the time user Bar is finished with implementing a feature, Foo committed and pushed something to the main repository. So basically the situation looks like this:

```
A---B---C---D    main repository
         \
          E      forked repository (where C=E)
           \
            F    barbranch on forked repository
```

Now how can stuff be brought back to normal in user Foo's repo?

Naively I would say:

```
# switch to the local master and merge barbranch into it
git checkout master
git pull
git pull upstream
git push
git merge barbranch
# merge conflicts occur
vi somefile
git commit -a
git rebase origin master
# this conflict occurs again
vi somefile
git commit -a
git status # says I'm on (no branch) ?!
git push
g    it checkout master
# conflict occurs again!
vi somefile
git commit -a
git push
# send merge request to user Foo
```

Finally this gives me three ugly commits instead of one.

Checking out the git-rebase documentation I found `git rebase --onto ...`. Though I cannot figure out what the exact command would be and would that whole process would look like in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends of the tree you want to get.

If you want a tree representing the real work history, you should not use "rebase" but only "merge"

```
# on bar repo
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master (fast-forward)
git merge barbranch
# resolve conflicts (adding resolved files)
git commit
git push upstream master
```

If you want to "linearize" the work with rebase, here is what you should do:

```
# on bar repo
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master (fast-forward)
git checkout barbranch
git rebase master
# resolve conflicts + commits (each commit will be processed separately: so you may need to do that several times if various commits are in conflict with the upstream)
git checkout master
git merge barbranch **(fast-forward after the rebase)**
git push upstream master
```

Comment: Thank you, yeah I want the "linearized" version. Just to clarify: Does it matter on which branch I do `git fetch upstream`? Each step of "resolve conflicts + commits" is in the end `vi somefile ; git commit -a`, right?

Comment: You can fetch from everywhere. Resolve conflicts = ("vi" + "git add resolved_file") for each conflict file + a final "git commit". This way is better when several files are in conflict: you can know everytime which conflicts files are not resolved yet with "git status".

Comment: This is really weird I'm getting messages like [this](http://pastebin.com/NFirzz6g). Though this branch has been created before the patch in the question has been accepted...

Answer (score 2):

I think the following scenario should be ok for your situation.

- Checkout master
- Pull the forked branch into your local master
- Manually fix the conflicts
- Commit the changes about conflict resolution
- Push to master

This will actually result in 3 commits into your master (you will have the commits E & F and your conflict resolution commit).